# How can I put HTML control on-click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Button with some HTML controls is there any way I can make those control fire in onClick event  in JavaScript

```
<input type="button" id="btncont" value="Continue" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse"; data-parent="#accordion"; data-target="#accordionThree" />
```

I want `data-toggle="collapse";` `data-parent="#accordion";` `data-target="#accordionThree"` to be fired on click event.

Comment: What do you mean you want those values to "fire"?

Comment: _"any way i can make those control fire in onclick event in javascript"_ What do you mean by "fire"?

Comment: You want to use accordion when click on your button , Right ?

Comment: yes I want to a onclick event make those control work

Comment: @guest271314 Fire in the sence i want those contol to work on a onclick event.

Comment: There are a number of ways you can do this... first, you can make onclick=function name () in the html, and do what ever you want with it in javascript. Or you can use jquery accordion... search google m8

Comment: what have to tried so far.? There are different ways this can be done.

Comment: _"Fire in the sence i want those contol to work on a onclick event."_ Can you describe "work"? Do you mean attach a `click` event to `data-toggle="collapse"`, where `collapse` is a `className` of an element?

Comment: you can put attribute (data-toggle="collapse"; data-parent="#accordion"; data-target="#accordionThree" ) in button click right ???

Answer (score 0):

After Click Check Attr. in click web browser click "F12" button and selecte button and see set attr.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btncont").click(function(){
      // Set Attribute in button
      $("#btncont").attr("data-toggle", "collapse");
      $("#btncont").attr("data-parent", "#accordion");
      $("#btncont").attr("data-targe", "#accordionThree");
     alert("Set All Attr in Button tag")
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="btncont" value="Continue" class="btn btn-primary"  />
```

Comment: how do i add data-toggle and data-parent in function myFunction();

Comment: you can put attribute (data-toggle="collapse"; data-parent="#accordion"; data-target="#accordionThree" ) in button click right ???